# Changing Checkbox Font To Bold using CSS In HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-tables

I need to change the font of a checkbox label in a table to bold when the checkbox is checked.

I have a table built and have some code to hide all rows of the table if header check box is unchecked. Now I want to click a checkbox that exists in each row and have the font of the text in the next cell become bold.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#HideValidationRows').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked)

      $('.AllValidationRows').fadeIn(100);
    else
      $('.AllValidationRows').fadeOut(100);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table 900px="" border="1" style="width: 900px; height: 63px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 63px;">
      <td style="height: 23px; background-color: #bdac73; width: 478px;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #000000;"> <strong> &nbsp; Verification, Validation &amp; Qualification</strong></span></td>
      <td style="width: 257px; background-color: #bdac73; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="HideValidationRows" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input id="boldCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="boldCheckbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 17px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;IQ/OQ/PQ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 22px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 21px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Process Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Labels Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Non-Current DPD Authority &amp; Derivative Dataset Archive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;First Article Inspection Report</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where did you attempt to do this? I see fadeIn() and fadeOut() but no bolding attempts.

Comment: You can attach a change event handler to the checkboxes that toggles a class on the parent tr.  Then you can have a css rule for that class to bold the last td in the tr.

Comment: I see no <label> elements

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('input[name="DV"]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').css("font-weight","bold");
    });
```

You might consider creating a css class that can be toggled for if someone unchecks a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#HideValidationRows').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked)
      $('.AllValidationRows').fadeIn(100);
    else
      $('.AllValidationRows').fadeOut(100);
  });
      
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change',function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parent('td').next('td').css({"font-weight":"bold","color":"red"});
     }else{
      $(this).parent('td').next('td').css({"font-weight":"normal","color":"black"});
     }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table 900px="" border="1" style="width: 900px; height: 63px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 63px;">
      <td style="height: 23px; background-color: #bdac73; width: 478px;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #000000;"> <strong> &nbsp; Verification, Validation &amp; Qualification</strong></span></td>
      <td style="width: 257px; background-color: #bdac73; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="HideValidationRows" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input id="boldCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="boldCheckbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 17px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;IQ/OQ/PQ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 22px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 21px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Process Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Labels Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Non-Current DPD Authority &amp; Derivative Dataset Archive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;First Article Inspection Report</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Most Welcome...:)

Comment: I am now trying to get the bolded font to change color as well. No luck. Have tried this:
$(this).parent('td').next('td').css("font-weight","bold","color:","red");
as well as:
  $(this).parent('td').next('td').css("font-weight","bold");
   $(this).parent('td').next('td').css("color:","red");

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need something to define one selector that can handle the event in all your checkboxes.

In the code you shared, we can see that in the first row (IQ/OQ/PQ), you have `id="boldCheckbox"` and `class="boldCheckbox"`, while in the others you only have `name="DV"`.

I recommend three options:

1. Change the `<input>` attributes, setting one `class` (like `boldCheckbox` that you already use in the first row) - *you can use  `name` too, but I recommend using it only in form submitting, setting it as a name/value pair*. In this case, we have the selector `$(".boldCheckbox")`;
2. Changing nothing, but here I recommend adding one `id` to your table, like `<table id="vvqtable">` and use the selector `$("#vvqtable input[type='checkbox']")`;
3. Use the class `AllValidationRows` in all the rows. The selector: `$(".AllValidationRows input[type='checkbox']")`.

---

Now, we need the function to set the second column into **bold**. We have two ways of doing so:

1. Using [`css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) and changing the attribute `font-weight` to `bold`; or
2. Creating one CSS class with `font-weight: bold;` and using [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

---

An example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#HideValidationRows').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked)
      $('.AllValidationRows').fadeIn(100);
    else
      $('.AllValidationRows').fadeOut(100);
  });
  
  $(".AllValidationRows input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('td').next('td').toggleClass('bold');
  });
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table 900px="" border="1" style="width: 900px; height: 63px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 63px;">
      <td style="height: 23px; background-color: #bdac73; width: 478px;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #000000;"> <strong> &nbsp; Verification, Validation &amp; Qualification</strong></span></td>
      <td style="width: 257px; background-color: #bdac73; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" id="HideValidationRows" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input id="boldCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="boldCheckbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 17px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;IQ/OQ/PQ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 22px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Design Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 21px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Process Validation</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Labels Verification</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Non-Current DPD Authority &amp; Derivative Dataset Archive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 22px;" class="AllValidationRows">
      <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; height: 22px;" td="">&nbsp; <input name="DV" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td style="width: 695px; height: 21px;" colspan="2">&nbsp;First Article Inspection Report</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Working Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) for the Selectors Level 4 specification which includes a `:has()` pseudoclass, which would allow you to do this using CSS only.

```
td:has(input:checked) + td label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

However this is [currently not supported in any browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility).

You could still do this with a CSS-only solution as long as your `<input>` and `<label>` elements were in the same parent element.

```css
input:checked + label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /><label for="checkbox">Design Verification</label>
```

But for now, if you want to have the `<input>` and `<label>` in different `<td>` elements, then you would need a javascript solution as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Give your checkbox a class say check1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.check1').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) 
        $('table td:last-child').css("font-weight","700");
        else
        $('table td:last-child').css("font-weight","400");
    });
});
```